# Rearrangement of absolutely convergent series proof.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question about the following part of a proof that a rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series converges to the same value as the original series.

*Proof. Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is absolutely convergent and let $z: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection. Pick $\epsilon > 0$. First find $N$ large such that for $n \geq N$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k| - \sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|\right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|a_k| < \epsilon.$$
Consider the maximum $M = \max\{z(1), z(2), z(3), \ldots , z(N)\}.$ Then for each $n \geq M$ the set
$$S_n = \{z(1), z(2), z(3), \ldots , z(n)\} \supset \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, N\}.$$*
$\ldots$

Why is this final line true?

Yes, we can always go far enough through the terms of the rearranged sequence to reach a point where $a_1, \ldots, a_N$ have all shown up. But isn't this just because $z$ is a bijection, and so each term of the original sequence shows up eventually in the rearranged sequence.

Why does $n \geq M$ make this certain?

Can't we have for example with $N = 10$ that

$$\{z(1), \ldots, z(N)\} = \{101, 102, 103, \ldots, 110\}$$

where $M = 110$ and we have $n \geq M \geq N$.

Therefore,

$$\{z(1), \ldots, z(N), \ldots, z(M), \ldots, z(n)\} = \{101, \ldots, 110, \ldots, 210, 211\} \not \supset \{1, \ldots, 10\}. $$

Is this a faulty counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that they meant to write

$M=\max\{z^{-1}(1),z^{-1}(2),\ldots,z^{-1}(N)\}$.